# ios Can I use MPMoviePlayerController to play .mp3 url

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

My app needs to play some music files, like .mp3. I would like to use MPMoviePlayerController because it has implemented all the UI stuff for me, i.e. I do not want to bother implementing progress slide bar and things like this.

I tested to use it to play a .mp3 file and it worked fine but I do not know if it is fine to use it to do this because its name says "movie player" and it seems it is supposed to play a movie. Would apple reject this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For playing audio from a file or memory, `AVAudioPlayer` is your best option but unfortunately it doesn't support a network stream while `MPMoviePlayerController` can
From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/) :

> An instance of the AVAudioPlayer class, called an audio player,
>   provides playback of audio data from a file or memory.
>
> Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you
>   are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low
>   I/O latency.

For the Apple validation I don't think that your application can be rejected because you're using the Media Player Framework to play an audio file. In fact [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007298) they explicitly say that you can do just that:

> Choose the right technology for your needs:
>
> To play the audio items in a user’s iPod library, or to play local or
>   streamed movies, use the Media Player framework. Classes in this
>   framework automatically support sending audio and video to AirPlay
>   devices such as Apple TV.

Not sure about performance and memory issues though!

Best of luck.